# Write a table by column

Tags: html, html-table

How can I write a table by column and not by row in HTML? Is it possible? As I know the standard method is by row like this:

```
<tr>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: @user3662273 I want for example to write the first column then the second then the third.If we want to create a table 10x10 I want the first column(1..10,1) to be added and then the second(1..10,2)

Comment: You could use floating <div>'s. Cells inside columns floated left. ... I guess?

Comment: @amphetamachine Can you show me an example?

Comment: @GeorgeMelidis Sure. http://jsfiddle.net/9ky816ts/

Comment: @GeorgeMelidis I think I pretty much nailed it here.... http://jsfiddle.net/m04rpbbk/

Comment: @amphetamachine Joking aside, I think this is really the only way to do it.  Might as well put it up as an answer, you'll get an upvote from me anyways.

Comment: See: ["How to create tables from column data instead of row data in HTML?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071864/how-to-create-tables-from-column-data-instead-of-row-data-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML tables are standardized to be defined left-to-right, top-to-bottom. Thus, the only way to do what you're asking is to reinvent the table using a different DOM structure.

For example:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="cell">Cell1</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell2</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell3</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="cell">Cell5</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell6</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell7</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="cell">Cell9</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell10</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell11</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    float: left;
}
.column {
    float: left;
}
.cell {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

See jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9ky816ts/

Note: the styling isn't perfect, but one can always play with it. You get the point.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>
   <td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
```

columns?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible Since The browser creates cells in the order :

First row, left to right; second row, left to right; then third row, left to right - and so on for as many rows and columns as are needed. It expects to "read" your html in exactly the same order - left to right, across and down the table. ie., **Row is created first**. see [Reference](http://www-cdr.stanford.edu/~petrie/jump5.htm)  for construction of HTML tables

If you want a table that may have only one row and `n` numbers of columns then write the tags as

```
<Table>
<tr>
   <td></td>............<td></td>
</tr>
</Table>
```

where `.` represent n number of `<td>` columns