# How to align Bootstrap columns one after one and one below one?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to create columns one after one and one below one at a same time?

Here is a sample image:

[image: Here is a sample image]

Comment: In this image, is each div independent from each other?

Comment: Yes, each div is independent (i.e. col-md-4+col-md-4+col-md-4...) but within one row

Comment: Well, does using rows in each column satisfies your question?

Comment: I don't think so. Because that will make only one column in a row below another row and so on...! My contents are dynamic.

Comment: Closely-related question: [HTML - Write a table by column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432473/html-write-a-table-by-column/25433112)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only with bootstrap, it is not possible. But you can use third-party library like masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

And you can combine bootstrap's grid functionality and masonry very simple.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="col-sm-4">...</div> // col instead of item
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

I also did this in one of my projects, and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the `row` class with `d-flex flex-wrap`.

That should work and also keep the columns responsive.