# For loops and table columns/rows

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, html-table

I have a table that allows people to book at a time and day, I can't figure out how to format the table so that it ends the column after the loop reaches 9 (from 10:00 to 18:00). If someone could point out where I should put any `<td>` or `<tr>` tags or anything I'd hugely appreciate it, here's the code I have at the moment.

```
<table width="579" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="78" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="78" scope="col">Monday</th>
    <th width="78" scope="col">Tuesday</th>
    <th width="78" scope="col">Wednesday</th>
    <th width="78" scope="col">Thursday</th>
    <th width="78" scope="col">Friday</th>
    <th width="78" scope="col">Saturday</th>
    <th width="78" scope="col">Sunday</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
   $days=array(
   1 => 'Monday',
   2 => 'Tuesday',
   3 => 'Wednesday',
   4 => 'Thursday',
   5 => 'Friday',
   6 => 'Saturday',
   7 => 'Sunday'
   );
  for($i=10;$i <=18; $i++){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th height="151" scope="row"><? echo $i; ?>:00</th>
        <td id="book">
            <?php
            $statement = "SELECT * 
                        FROM booking
                        WHERE time = $i
                        AND day = '$days[$d]'";
            $booked = $db_link->query($statement) or die ($db_link->error);
            if($booked->num_rows==0){
                ?><a href="booking.php?day=<? echo $days[$d]; ?>&t=<? echo $i; ?>&b=1">Book</a>
                <?php
            }else{ ?>
                    BOOKED 
                    <?
                }?>
       </td>
   </tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you want the resultant table to look like? You can use the code snippet tool to add an example to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you are creating the table row-wise.. Therefore you will have to append data to the table row by row.

There are some workarounds to print your column data in a table..

**1. Store your data in arrays and then append it on rows.**

*i.e.* store each element of a column in an separate array and print each array over a row..

*e.g.* column will be  `$a[0]   $b[0]   $c[0]`

```
        $a[0]   $a[1]   $a[2]    // $a elements for first row
        $b[0]   $b[1]   $b[2]    // $b elements for second row
        $c[0]   $c[1]   $c[2]    // $c elements for third row
```

**2. Invert the table using javascript.**

You can print the columns as rows in a table, and invert the table so that the rows become columns.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127030/4513747) is an answer which contains a working jsFiddle to support this task.