# Writing table in columns rather that rows (Extension)

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

This is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071864/how-to-create-tables-from-column-data-instead-of-row-data-in-html).

I want to input data into the table in columns, not rows. The jquery example from the linked question works nicely except it moves the headings () as well. I am wondering how to leave the headings and just rotate the content. I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            $("table").each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var newrows = [];
                $this.find("tr").each(function() {
                    var i = 0;
                    $(this).find("td").each(function() {
                        i++;
                        if (newrows[i] === undefined) {
                            newrows[i] = $("<tr></tr>");
                        }
                        newrows[i].append($(this));
                    });
                });
                $this.find("tr").remove();
                $.each(newrows, function() {
                    $this.append(this);
                });
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

But the headings just disappear.

Comment: I just realized my answer might not solve your problem.  You want to keep the headers at the top?  They probably won't be useful after the rotation or match the new number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that will "flip" a table with `th`'s defined.

1. It figures out how many rows there are;
2. It sets up some templates
3. it then runs through the headers and reads the column transcribing it to a row.
4. Adds that row to a new table.
5. Replaces the old table with the new one.

**Note** any handlers you had on the old table would disappear, and because the table doesn't have any `th`s the code will not work to switch it back.  This is only meant as a starting point.

```js
$("button.flip").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $table = $(this).prev("table");
  var $newTable = $("<table>");
  var $newRowTemplate = $("<tr>");
  var rowCount = $table.find("tr").length;
  for (let i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
    $newRowTemplate.append("<td>");
  }

  $.each($table.find("tr:first-child > th"), function(col, cell) {
    var $newRow = $newRowTemplate.clone();
    var txt = "";
    $($newRow.find("td")[0]).html($(cell).text());
    for (let y = 1; y <= rowCount; y++) {
      txt = $table
        .find(`tr:nth-child(${y}) > td:nth-child(${col+1})`).text();
      $($newRow.find("td")[y]).html(txt);
    }
    $newTable.append($newRow);
  });
  //$(this).after($newTable);
  if (!$newTable.is(":empty")) {
    $table.remove();
    $(this).before($newTable);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student</th>
      <th>Class</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>History</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sarah</td>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam</td>
      <td>Math</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="flip">flip</button>
```

**Edit** with a little effort I was able to make this work and then reverse itself, again I suspect any event handlers will be lost.

```js
$("button.flip").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $table = $(this).prev("table"); //orig table reference
  var $newTable = $("<table>"); //new table placeholder
  var rowCount = $table.find("tr").length; //the number of rows in the orig table

  //loop through the first rows cells
  $.each($($table.find("tr")[0]).children(), function(col, cell) {
    var $newRow = $("<tr>"); //create a new row
    $newRow.append($(cell).clone()); //append the current cell
    //traverse the column appending the cells to the row as we go
    for (let y = 1; y <= rowCount; y++) {
      $newRow.append($($($table.find("tr")[y]).children()[col]).clone());
    }
    $newTable.append($newRow); //put the new row in the new table
  });
  //if I managed to do some work lets remove the old table and replace it with the new one
  if (!$newTable.is(":empty")) {
    $table.remove();
    $(this).before($newTable);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student</th>
      <th>Class</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>History</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sarah</td>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam</td>
      <td>Math</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn</td>
      <td>Javascript</td>
      <td>D-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="flip">flip</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can keep the 'th' elements only in another table at the top of this table. And that way you don't have to invert the headings. Only invert the down table with the data.