# React, how to construct a table by columns instead of by rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui, next.js

I am working with react, I want to create a material-ui table with certain caracteristics.
I have an array of elements where every element represent a column of the table, each column's elemnt has a name and a number of how many cells cover.

so for example a column is something like this:

```
    column1 =[
{name: 'A1', cells:2 },
{name: 'A2', cells:1},
{name: 'A3', cells:2},
{name: 'A4', cells:3},
...
]

column2 =[
{name: 'B1', cells:4 },
{name: 'B2', cells:1},
{name: 'B3', cells:3},
{name: 'B4', cells:1},
...
]
```

And the whole table array is something like:

```
table=[column1, column2,...]
```

the result of column1 and column2:

[image]

I need something similar to Mui.TableRow but for iterate columns.

I know that every cell would be like this:

```
{column1.map((e) => {
    <Mui.TableCell style={{border: '4px solid grey'}} rowSpan={e.cells} >
         {e.name}
     </Mui.TableCell>
}
```

But I dont know how to separate each column.

If someone could give me advice of how to do this or another approach it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `div` instead of  table components, and make your `Column` component which renders each column for you, and put them all together.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974170

> In modern browsers you can achieve this by redefining the TR and TD tags behavior in CSS. Given the HTML in your question attach the next CSS style:
>
> ```
> table {
>   display: table;
> }
> table tr {
>   display: table-cell;
> }
> table tr td {
>   display: block;
> }
> ```