# C# Web API: Looping over JSON Object Array

Tags: c#, json

I am building a C# Web API and once you POST data to the endpoint, it will generate a HTML email with the values posted.

Unfortunately I'm stuck on how to parse and loop over the JSON array that contains key/value pairs and ultimately generate a HTML table row as a result.

Sample JSON data im testing with:

```
{
   "Submitter":[
      {
         "Obj1":[
            "test",
            "test2"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Obj2":[
            "test3",
            "test4"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Code:

```cs
    public class TestingController : ControllerBase
    {
        public object Submitter { get; set; }

        public string POST([FromBody] TestingController data)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.Submitter);
            var jsonObjects = JObject.Parse(json);
            var submitData = jsonObjects["Submitter"];

            string body = "";

            foreach (var item in submitData)
            {
                body += $"{item["Obj1"]}"; // Not working
            }

            return body;
        }
    }
```

Desired html render once being able to successfully loop the array:

```cs
body += $"<tr><td>{item["Obj1"]}</td><td>{item["Obj2"]}</td></tr>"
```

**EDIT**

I still struggling but slowly getting one step closer:

```cs
    public class TestingController : ControllerBase
    {
        public List<SubmitterObjects> Submitter { get; set; }

        public class SubmitterObjects
        {
            public List<string> Obj1 { get; set; }
            public List<string> Obj2 { get; set; }
        }

        public string POST([FromBody] TestingController data)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            dynamic myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            string body = "";

            foreach (var item in myDeserializedClass.Submitter)
            {
                body += $"<tr><td>{item.Obj1}</td><td>{item.Obj2}</td></tr>";
            }

            return body;
        }
    }
```

Result (weird):

```html
<tr><td>[
  "test",
  "test2"
]</td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>[
  "test3",
  "test4"
]</td></tr>
```

Desired HTML table result:

```
| Object 1 | Object 2 |
|----------|----------|
| Test     | Test 3   |
| Test 2   | Test 4   |
```

Comment: It is not quite clear how `Obj1`and `Obj2` should be represented in the resulting HTML. Could you please add the desired HTML output. Also consider using a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0) instead of concatenating `body += ...`

Comment: ```body``` will contain a table which is why im trying to append Obj1 & Obj2 to it. Although what im really trying to achieve here is being able to successfully loop over the JSON array, the HTML generation part of it is easy and I will look into String Builder

Comment: You should be able to access the contents of your `item` by [JArray.ChildrenTokens](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_ChildrenTokens.htm).

Comment: Hmm im looking into it but im not too sure how to implement it

Comment: @Filburt I just made an edit, seems like im able to loop the array but the html output is a bit weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few mistakes and bad practices in the code. I've commented them below:

```
    public class TestingController : ControllerBase
    {
        // Bad practice: Having an object with type "object". Using strict types is encouraged
        public object Submitter { get; set; }

        // Bad practice: The type of "data" is the same as the controller.
        public string POST([FromBody] TestingController data)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.Submitter);
            var jsonObjects = JObject.Parse(json);
            var submitData = jsonObjects["Submitter"];

            string body = "";

            foreach (var item in submitData)
            {
                // Here the item["Obj1"] is not a string, it's an array, so you get an error.
                // Bad practice: Returning an HTML right in the controller. 
                // If you have a separate frontend, then it would be better to just return
                // the results in an array or json, and format it in frontend instead
                body += $"{item["Obj1"]}"; // Not working
            }

            return body;
        }
    }
```

And here's the fixed version of the code.
First, have strongly typed classes:

```
public class Submitter
{
    public List<string> Obj1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> Obj2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyData
{
    public List<Submitter> Submitter { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify the `Post` method like this to iterate over the items:

```
    public string POST([FromBody] MyData data) // Note: The type is changed to MyData
    {
        // Note: We don't need the deserializing logic anymore, as it's already automatically done by .net
        string body = "";
        foreach (var item in data.Submitter)
        {
            if (item.Obj1 != null) {
                body += "<tr>";
                // Note: You can use LINQ to simplify this loop...
                foreach (var objItem in item.Obj1) {
                    body += $"<td>{objItem}</td>";
                }
                body += "</tr>";
            }
            if (item.Obj2 != null) {
                body += "<tr>";
                foreach (var objItem in item.Obj2) {
                    body += $"<td>{objItem}</td>";
                }
                body += "</tr>";
            }
        }

        return body;
    }
```

Also please note that you're filling the table based on column data instead of row, so you'll need to do the small changes in the css like it's done [in this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974170/5935112) answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response however im running into an error ```Object reference not set to an instance of an object``` when trying to loop over ```item.Obj1``` as an example. Any ideas?

Comment: ```System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at APITesting.Controllers.Testing2Controller.POST(MyData data)```

Comment: That's because the items of the Submitter sometimes are type of `Obj1` and sometimes type of `Obj2`. I've added a null check to fix that issue. Please take a look at the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for that its working perfectly. The other thing im confused about is how I would be able to render ```body += $"<tr><td>{item["Obj1"]}</td><td>{item["Obj2"]}</td></tr>"``` within foreach so all items are being displayed on the same html table row

Comment: Obj1 and Obj2 are arrays, so the line you wrote above will not work. Can you please provide the expected result that you want? It will help us to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: I did in my original question, under "desired": ```body += $"<tr><td>{item["Obj1"]}</td><td>{item["Obj2"]}</td></tr>"```

Comment: `item["Obj1"]` can't be in the body as it's an array. Instead there can be the items of that array like `item["Obj1"][0]` or `item["Obj1"][1]`

Comment: Thanks, I just made an edit to my question for my desired result. Is it possible at all to achieve that result?

Comment: @ayushlal, I've updated the answer accordingly, now it produces the desired result. Also please don't forget to take a look at the note that I've added to the answer. It will make the table to look like the one you've provided in the question.